# How to draw multiple circles in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make multiple circles in canvas but all the time my code creates only one circle. I think I'm doing everything right, I checked few sites how to do it and nothing helped. My code looks like that:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
let hole = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let holes = [];

let hx =  Math.random() * canvas.width ;
let hy =  Math.random() * canvas.height ;
let radius = 25;

document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', onStartClick);

function onStartClick() {
 // somecode..

    makeHoles();

}

function makeHoles() {
    hole.fillStyle = 'rgb(84, 93, 139)';
    hole.beginPath();
    for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
        hole.moveTo(hx,hy);
        hole.arc(
            hx,
            hy,
            radius,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI,
            true
        );
    }
    hole.stroke();
    hole.fill();
        
    holes.push(hole);

}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("canvas")`, not `document.querySelector(".canvas")`. The `.` refers to a class, whereas you are looking for the element by a tag.

Comment: the class name is also canvas, anyways changing this it doesn't help

Comment: That helps - this is why you need your full code! Without the HTML, it's hard to work with the problem. Check out my solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's not drawing because you are not reinitializing the variables. Just move `hx` and `hy` into the function.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
let hole = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let holes = [];

let radius = 25;

function onStartClick() {
  // somecode..

  makeHoles();

}

function makeHoles() {
  var hx = Math.random() * canvas.width;
  var hy = Math.random() * canvas.height;
  hole.fillStyle = 'rgb(84, 93, 139)';
  hole.beginPath();
  for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    hole.moveTo(hx, hy);
    hole.arc(
      hx,
      hy,
      radius,
      0,
      2 * Math.PI,
      true
    );
  }
  hole.stroke();
  hole.fill();

  holes.push(hole);

}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
<button onclick="onStartClick()">Start!</button>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked when I put 'hx' and 'hy' inside the for loop

Answer (score 1):

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
let hole = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let holes = [];
let radius = 25;

function makeHoles() {
    for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
       let hx =  Math.random() * canvas.width ;
       let hy =  Math.random() * canvas.height ;
        hole.beginPath();
        hole.fillStyle = `rgb(84, 93, 139)`;
        hole.moveTo(hx,hy);
        hole.arc(
            hx,
            hy,
            radius,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI,
            true
        );
        
         hole.stroke();
         hole.fill();
         holes.push(hole);
    }
}

 makeHoles();
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```